# To add a sidebar to iCal 5.x in Lion: is there an API, or would a hack be required?

Tags: api, osx-lion, icalendar

## Two parts to this question

**Does Apple provide** in Lion, Mac OS X 10.7 (Build 11A511) an API that might enable a third party developer to add a sidebar to iCal 5.0 (1535)?

**If not provided by Apple**: what would be the best starting point for a hack?

The first that comes to mind:

- [SIMBL](http://culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) — not specifically updated for Lion, but certainly proving itself good for many purposes.

### Context

In this question I'm focused solely on the sidebar:

- primarily for a **list of calendars** — grouped as they were, or better than, in Snow Leopard
- with only minimal interest in mini-months, which were optional in the sidebar in Snow Leopard (it's [trivially simple to switch between year, month and other views in iCal 5.x](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3211397))
- integrated with iCal (not running as a separate application).

This question, not for the possibility of [detaching the aqua popover](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010720) — that might form a separate question.

In Apple Support Communities:

- [sidebar missing from iCal in Lion — seeking a third party product to restore lost functionality](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3194676)

I see [Mac OS X v10.6 to v10.7 API Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/MacOSXLionAPIDiffs/) and other documents, but I'm not a developer so I'm not sure of the best starting point for browsing and understanding APIs. (I have archaic ADC Online membership and more, but for my level of interest/understanding etc., I have chosen to not enrol in the [Mac Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/).)

Thank you!

## Update, February 2012

It seems that for the developer preview of Mountain Lion, Apple has restored the sidebar to iCal. Great news, if this feature makes it to release … but still, an answer to this Lion-specific question will be appreciated.